# Why "я учился в многих школе" instead of "я учился в много школе"?

Tags: грамматика

If i write:я учился в многих школе there is a meaning, i think that the understand that the  studied in many schools at same time is possible.

Now if i write:я учился в много школе here seems to be ugly, at least for me, but the translation looks better because seems that i studied in a lot of schools , what i should do?

Comment: What is your mother tongue?

Comment: casey i truly do not know, i was born in brazil (portuguese) but in home my family speak arabic, what difference may you infer from it?

Comment: @YassinRany the difference is that English and Chinese belong to group of Analytic languages, whereas Russian in the Synthetic group. An explanation to the question "How it works" (it was the question you edited later) may?/should?/not? include a part that make a contrast to synthetic languages. Learning Russian "How it works" can be a challenge for English native speakers without it.

Comment: please if you do not mind i will like it, i changed the title because few persons was entering in the post, i though i should change the title. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You are asking why [one incorrect Russian phrase] instead of [second incorrect Russian phrase], that indicates that you do not put any research effort beforehand.

Comment: @  shabunc what does that sentence even mean, dude?) Maybe put a bit of effort in yourself))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The (only) correct grammar here is **Я учился во многих школах**; while you shouldn't worry about "studying in many schools at the same time" (you'd need to explicitly say **сразу во многих** or **сразу в нескольких**), there is a different kind of vague problem about this wording, in that it sounds more like "I studied in many *of the* schools". Russian doesn't have articles, of course, but some random distinctions based on definitiveness turn up every now and then; **многие** sort of implies that more information about those particular schools is forthcoming ("in many of the schools which...") or has already been given.

**Я учился в нескольких школах** doesn't have this problem; I don't know how many schools we're talking about here; I went to five, but it's still something I would say, i.e. I don't feel "several" is an understatement. If you insist on "many", though, it's probably better to reword as **Я сменил много школ**. (Another option, theoretically, would be **Я учился во множестве школ**, but that would most likely be an *over*statement unless we're talking about a really extraordinary number of schools, maybe about ten or more.)